# Javascript Add Class Code Efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery

The scenario is fairly simple. I built a function that takes strings as an argument. I then add these strings as classes on the body of the document.

Now, these classes can change. I want to remove the old classes and add the new ones. I want to do this without killing any existing body classes so: `document.body.className = "";` is out of the question.

My solution works fine, but seems to be bloated. I think I may have conflated the code around the idea of storing `prev` variables outside of the function scope.

Here's a link to a JS Fiddle with the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/tgfer9ya/2/

Does anyone have suggestions around how I can streamline this or make it more efficient?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var currRegion = "";
var currLocale = "";
var currLang = "";

setBodyClasses("AMERICA", "en_US", "en");

function setBodyClasses(region, locale, lang) {
  region = region.toLowerCase();
  locale = locale.toLowerCase();
  lang = lang.toLowerCase();

  if (currRegion !== region) {
    $("body").removeClass(currRegion).addClass(region);
    currRegion = region;
  }

  if (currLocale !== locale) {
    $("body").removeClass(currLocale).addClass(locale);
    currLocale = locale;
  }

  if (currLang !== lang) {
    $("body").removeClass(currLang).addClass(lang);
    currLang = lang;
  }  
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgfer9ya/3/)